# Oracle SQL overlap between begin date and end date in 2 or more records

Tags: sql, oracle, date, aggregate, overlap

Database `my_table`:

```
id     seq     start_date     end_date
1      1       01-01-2017     02-01-2017
1      2       07-01-2017     09-01-2017
1      3       11-01-2017     11-01-2017
2      1       20-01-2017     20-01-2017
3      1       01-02-2017     02-02-2017
3      2       03-02-2017     04-02-2017
3      3       08-01-2017     09-02-2017
3      4       09-01-2017     10-02-2017
3      5       10-01-2017     12-02-2017
```

My requirement is to get the first date (normally seq 1 start date) and end date (normally last seq end date) and the number of dates occurred during all seq for each unique ID.

Date occurred:

```
id      1              2              3
        01-01-2017     20-01-2017     01-02-2017
        02-01-2017                    02-02-2017
        07-01-2017                    03-02-2017
        08-01-2017                    04-02-2017
        09-01-2017                    08-02-2017
        11-01-2017                    09-02-2017
                                      10-02-2017
                                      11-02-2017
                                      12-02-2017
total   6              1              9
```

Here is the result I want:

```
id     start_date     end_date       num_date
1      01-01-2017     11-01-2017     6
2      20-01-2017     20-01-2017     1
3      01-02-2017     12-02-2017     9
```

I have tried

```
SELECT   id
         , MIN(start_date)
         , MAX(end_date)
         , SUM(end_date - start_date + 1)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY id
```

and this SQL statement work fine in id 1 and 2 since there is no overlap date between begin date and end date. But for id 3, the result `num_date` is 11. Could you please suggest the SQL statement to solve this problem? Thank you.

One more question: The date in database is in `datetime` format. How do I convert it to `date`. I tried to use `TRUNC` function but it sometimes convert date to yesterday instead.
[image]

Comment: Is that the only kind of overlap possible in your data, the end date of an interval equal to the start date of the next? Or can two intervals overlap for more than one day?

Comment: There will be no overlap intervals.

Comment: Can you give an example where TRUNC truncates a date with time-of-day to YESTERDAY? I've never seen that (and honestly I don't believe it).

Comment: Re: the image attached showing TRUNC. Could it be that the START_DTE is in a different timezone? Oracle doesn't have a "datetime" format that I know of but it could be TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Comment: ??  `TRUNC` should have the time portion of `00:00:00`, how can you get a result like that? What is the data type of start_dte and end_dte? (You can find out by running `DESCRIBE MY_TABLE`.)

Comment: Thank you @bbrumm. The problem is the different timezone.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type - it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and **both** have a time component (`TIMESTAMP` also has fractional seconds and, for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`, a time zone).

Comment: @lvlack - Even the time zone explanation makes sense in one case only: if the data type is TIMESTAMP WITH **LOCAL** TIMEZONE. Is that it?

Comment: @mathguy - the data type is `DATE`. I casted my date to `TIMESTAMP`, `TRUNC(CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP))`, but still not work even I convert timezone as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count how many times an `end_date` equals the following `start_date`. For this you need to use the `lag()` or the `lead()` analytic function. You can use a `case` expression for the comparison, but alas you can't wrap the case expression within a `COUNT` or `SUM` in the same query; you need a subquery and an outer query.

Something like this; not tested, since you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to recreate your sample data.

```
select   id, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date,
         sum(end_date - start_date + 1 - flag) as num_days
from     ( select id, start_date, end_date, 
                  case when start_date = lag(end_date) 
                            over (partition by id order by end_date) then 1
                                                                     else 0 end as flag
           from   my_table
         )
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       MIN( start_date ) AS start_date,
       MAX( end_date )   AS end_date,
       SUM( end_date - start_date + 1 ) AS num_days
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         GREATEST(
           start_date,
           COALESCE(
             LAG( end_date ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq ) + 1,
             start_date
           )
         ) AS start_date,
         end_date
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  start_date <= end_date
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: The OP does not count the number of distinct items; he is counting all the days between start_date and end_date. That may be 8 days but the count will just be 2.

Comment: Another thought (unrelated here, since for what you propose you do need `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`) - to "normalize" a non-normal table with `UNION ALL`, it is more efficient to `UNPIVOT`, since that requires reading the base table just once. Just learned this myself recently, and it is indeed a significant improvement.